# how to transfer combobox interface to propertygrid elegantly

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've decided to update my AutoCAD app to property grid to match its GUI.
so far, I've used few comboboxes to show printer properties and would like to put it inside a propertyBox instead.

because I've been using MVP concept, I've had most of the properties listed in IList type and it worked like a charm with comboboxes.

however, propertyBox doesn't work with IList but requires List type to show the item in dropdowns.

what would be the best way to achieve this port? Since I'm not that eager to rewrite the whole code.

ty.

my IList:

```
IList<string> Printers { set; get; }
IList<string> Papers { set; get; }
IList<string> PlotStyles { set; get; }
```

my Combobox value update:

```
public IList<string> Printers
{
    get { return (IList<string>)this.Printer.DataSource; }
    set { this.Printer.DataSource = value; }
}
```

should I create a duplicate property    `List<string> PrintersConverted` that gets copied properties of `"IList<string> Printers"` everytime the IList property gets changed... or is there a more elegant way?

also, keep in mind that these changes need to be "bidirectional" so when I change something in property box, it reflects back to Model/Presenter

Comment: What comboboxes were intended for? Do you have properties such as SelectedPrinter, SelectedPaper, and SelectedPlotStyle in another class? If so, that another class should be used with the PropertyGrid, and the class containing collection properties should be used as the source for your custom property editor.

Comment: comboboxes "Printers", "Papers",... are populated with elements from "model", and user would select the desired setting which would then be thrown back to model. I never have them as list objects, since they are dynamically extracted through API, and cast to IList directly. but your POV is usefull since it gives me an idea I didnt consider so far. I was trying to sort things out in "View", didnt consider so far to take a look back at model.